# How to run python program on my windows system after installation using notepad++ or dreamviewer

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new for python i installed python 3.6.1 on my windows 7 system after that i searched a lot but i cannot understand.please help me how to create a new python program using notepad++ or adobe dream viewer...

Comment: Please look at the documentation online. https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html

Comment: i opened python 3.6.1 shell and tested with this code print "hello" but print "hello"
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: Youtube setting notepad++ up for python3.

Comment: @hameed with `python3`, there is no longer a `print` statement, but now only a `print()` function. You need to call `print("Hello")`. The previous versions of Python used a `print` statement which was not a function so it didn't require parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on https://docs.python.org/3.6/faq/windows.html instead, since that is the version of python have installed.

Comment: i'm unableto understang that document.i installed python 3.6.1 on my computer system after that where will i write python code and how to run?

Comment: Write code and save file as filename.py and Go to terminal at code file location and type" python filename.py"

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pycharm IDE to code python. It is easy and user friendly. Download it using following link. use community edition.
[Pycharm Download](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)
Since you have alredy installed python, you can use that interpreter for pycharm.